# 未ログイン時に表示されるページ上部のバナーが一部英語になっている。

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

### 不具合事象

未ログイン状態で、ページ上部に表示されるバナーの一部文章が英語になっています。

**以前のバナー** ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) にて [2019 年 7 月 22 日のバナー](https://web.archive.org/web/20190722201938/https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)を確認)
[image: 以前のバナーはすべて日本語になっている]

**新しいバナー**
[image: 新しいバナーは左側の部分だけ英語になっている]

---

### 原因

[traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win/) で「以前のバナー」と「新しいバナー」の文章を読み比べると、内容の変化はほとんどありませんが、最後の一文と登録ボタンの文章のみ若干変更があり、それによって文章全体が英語に戻ってしまったのではないかと思います。

**以前のバナーの文章**

> $Name$ is a question and answer site for $Audience$. Join them; it only takes a minute

**新しいバナーの文章**

> $Name$ is a question and answer site for $Audience$. It only takes a minute to sign up.

---

### 翻訳案

英語どころか日本語すらままならないですが、念のため翻訳案を書いておきます。

**現在の文章**

> スタック・オーバーフロー is a question and answer site for プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心な人. It only takes a minute to sign up.
>   [Sign up to join this community]

**翻訳案**

> スタック・オーバーフローはプログラマーとプログラミングに熱心な人向けのQ&Aサイトです。登録にはたった 1 分しかかかりません。
>   [このコミュニティに登録する]

Comment: supa さん、翻訳案どうもありがとうございました！m_ _m。先ほどnekketsuuuさんが Traducirに直接入力くださった訳（supaさんの翻訳案から少し進化した版）を採用させていただきましたので反映まで少しお待ちくださいませ。
https://ja.traducir.win/string/12051
https://ja.traducir.win/string/12052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 解決

[@aki さんにコメントいただいた](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3047/%E6%9C%AA%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E4%B8%8A%E9%83%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E4%B8%80%E9%83%A8%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B#comment2835_3047)日本語訳の反映を確認したので、そのスクリーンショットをもってこの質問を解決済みにしたいと思います。

[image: バナーの英語部分が日本語へ翻訳された画像]

---

[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) さん、 [@nekketsuuu](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) さん、対応していただき、どうもありがとうございました。